# need to check already application installed or not using custom installer class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've to create one C# setup project application, at that time while installing i also include custom actions - install to filezilla server . Before install filezilla server need to check ,if it's already installed or not, if yes means installing application alone otherwise install both application & filezilla server. 
   is there any installer class to accomplish this event . waiting for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Microsoft.Win32 namespace for registry classes:

```
    string regKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regKey))
    {
        if (key.GetSubKeyNames().Any(keyName => key.OpenSubKey(keyName).GetValue("DisplayName") == "My App's Display Name"))
            Console.WriteLine("Already installed...");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Start installing...");
    }
```