# Check if foxit reader is installed?

Tags: c#, pdf, installation, foxit, foxit-reader

Using C# I want to detect whether foxit reader is installed on a windows machine. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Wich was the option that you tried and did not work?

Comment: I did not try any approach as of yet @Freeman, I'm looking to put my best foot forward. Any suggestions as to where I should start?

Comment: Actually there are two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908850/get-installed-applications-in-a-system) is here.
You should look through registry and find the name "foxit reader"

Comment: Strangely enough @Dmitry I opened up regedit on my machine and manually iterated through the list but could not find an entry for foxit reader although I have foxit reader 64 bit installed on my machine. So is this method foolproof?

Comment: Did you look in "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" in both current user and local machine? And in @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"?

Comment: I finally found it in this location @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Foxit Reader_is1" @Dmitry. I'm wondering whether this is an arbitrary location or a 64 bit installation of foxit always installs it's registry keys here? Now what about 32 bit machines? Or should I iterate through all the locations that you've indicated and check for the DisplayName/Install Location?

Comment: I think 32 bit machines don't have Wow6432Node node at all and you should iterate through all the locations to check the installation

Comment: Wow6432Node is where all 32bit applications in 64bit systems write their data

Comment: On a related note @Dmitry how can I detect in C# if a windows machine is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

- Take a blank machine.
- Install FoxIt Reader.
- Look where it has been installed.
- Use the `File.Exists` function together with `Environment.GetSpecialFolder` to check for the executable to be present.

Alternatively, if the path may vary where it has been installed, you could:

- Take a blank machine.
- Install FoxIt Reader.
- Look for Registry keys that have been added.
- Use the `RegistryKey` functions to check for existance of related keys.

Answer (score 0):

Files could be installed incorrectly. The same applies for registry keys that are stored by the Application itself. A `File.Exists` does not actually indicate it has been installed (and registered as a viewer).

I would personally check the Windows Installer database for the `Product`.
[checking the uninstall registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7722393/296526) is a possible approach, however you can also invoke [MsiQueryProductState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  using windows API calls.