# Create an installer that requires installing other app in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I'm trying to create an installer in VS2010.

My situation is: I have 2 app, during installing a application, I need to check if the other app exists or not. If it exists, just install the first app, otherwise install both of them. How can I do this in VS2010. I've searched and find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721795/need-to-check-already-application-installed-or-not-using-custom-installer-class). But I don't know where I can put these codes.

Any instruction in details would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will want to look into creating a [Custom BootStrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

From above link:

> The Setup program is a generic installer that can be configured to detect and install redistributable components such as Windows Installer (.msi) files and executable programs. The installer is also known as a bootstrapper. It is programmed through a set of XML manifests that specify the metadata to manage the installation of the component.
>
> The bootstrapper first detects whether any of the prerequisites are already installed. If prerequisites are not installed, first the bootstrapper shows the license agreements. Second, after the end-user accepts the license agreements, the installation begins for the prerequisites. Otherwise, if all the prerequisites are detected, the bootstrapper just starts the application installer.